# Java - Modifying an element from every object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to write a method that will increase the `relationship` element of the `Lord` object it is performed on by 10, and increase the same element of every other object in the ArrayList by 3. The code I have causes the loop to iterate 6 times when it should only iterate 2 times. Can anyone see what might be causing this behaviour? Below is the relevant code and stack trace lines:

**MainTest.java**

```
public class MainTest {

 private ArrayList<Lord> baratheons;
 private ArrayList<Lord> starks;

//Setup & Teardown

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    baratheons = new ArrayList<Lord>();
    baratheons.add( new Lord("Robert", 15));
    baratheons.add( new Lord("Renly", -5));
    baratheons.add( new Lord("Stannis", 30));

    starks = new ArrayList<Lord>();
    starks.add( new Lord("Robb", -60));
    starks.add( new Lord("Eddard", 0));
    starks.add( new Lord("Jon", 90));
}

@AfterEach
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    baratheons = null;
}

//tests

@Test
public void testGratefulLord() {
    int x = baratheons.get(0).getRelationship();
    baratheons.get(0).giveFief(baratheons, baratheons.get(0));
    assertEquals(baratheons.get(0).getRelationship(), (x+=10));     
}


@Test
public void testAlliesApprove() {
    int x = starks.get(0).getRelationship();
    starks.get(0).giveFief(starks, starks.get(0));
    assertEquals(starks.get(1).getRelationship(), x+3);
}
```

**Lord.java**

```
public void giveFief(ArrayList<Lord> arrayListLord, Lord lordGivenFief) {
    lordGivenFief.relationship += 10;

    ArrayList<Lord> temp = new ArrayList<Lord>();
    temp.add(lordGivenFief);
    arrayListLord.remove(lordGivenFief);

    ArrayList<Lord> alliesArrayList = new ArrayList<Lord>(arrayListLord);

    for (int i = 0; i<(alliesArrayList.size()); i++) {
        alliesArrayList.get(i).setRelationship(relationship+=3);
        System.out.printf("I have iterated! The current index is %d \n", i);
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at mainPackage.Lord.giveFief(Lord.java:28)
    at mainPackage.MainTest.testGratefulLord(MainTest.java:40)
```

**EDIT: AssertionFailedError Traces**

*testGratefulLord()*

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <28> but was: <25>

*testAlliesApprove()*

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <-44> but was: <-57>

Comment: In Lord.java, your loop condition should check using strict lesser than (`<`), not lesser than or equals (`<=`). In a collection of size 2, this means you would also be checking index 2, but since collections are zero-indexed your list only contains indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: Paul Benn is right. What about using a for-loop without checking size and index? Try: `for (Lord l: alliesArrayList) { l.setRelationship ...`

Comment: More info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html

Comment: I added the `=` just as a test, forgot to remove it before posting. I'll try the other way now.